# The order adjective and definite article

Tags: adjectives, definite-article

> As shown in the graph, Mexico has * over double * number of Spanish speakers of any other countries.

Where is the correct place of definite article (the) in above sentence? I added asterisks as place holders for the definite articles.

Comment: Here, "double" is not an adjective of the conventional kind.  It is a predeterminer (and described as such by https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/double , http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/double , https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/double ).  A predeterminer is a type of determiner that comes before the article or other determiner.  "Both" is another example.  So we say "both the" or "both those", "both my", etc.(not "my both", etc). ( http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/predeterminer )

Answer (score 1):

In this case you would put "the" before "number."

There are cases where a definite article comes before adverbs and adjectives, such as in the sentence:

> Mexico has **the most** Spanish speakers of any country.

The way you determine where to put the definite article is by determining whether the noun requires a definite article *without* the modifiers.

Since you wouldn't say

> Mexico has number of Spanish speakers

you need a definite article before the noun. If the noun doesn't require a definite article, as in the phrase:

> Mexico has Spanish speakers

then you use a definite article to refer to the modifier itself, as in "Mexico has **the *most*** Spanish speakers."

So in your case, since "number" requires a definite article, you put it right before the noun.

> Mexico has *over double **the** number* of Spanish speakers...

Comment: Thanks. I fear your answer is not clear enough. What is the pos of "over double"? As  determiners usually come first, the question is when they do not come first.